# Thread stopping from outside user input?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, cmd

So I have the following problem:

I have a small application that is run through command line args. What it does is it takes the arguments and starts a thread with a server running in it.

I know I can make a stoppable thread like this:

```
import threading

class StoppableThread(threading.Thread):
    """Thread class with a stop() method. The thread itself has to check
    regularly for the stopped() condition."""

    def __init__(self):
        super(StoppableThread, self).__init__()
        self._stop_event = threading.Event()

    def stop(self):
        self._stop_event.set()

    def stopped(self):
        return self._stop_event.is_set()
```

But my problem is that my application will still be running and the only way I could interact with it would be to send the signal through some other way.

This would also solve my dilemma to start multiple servers on demand while the application is still running

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    args = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Process some arguments.')
    args.add_argument('-start', help='Start the server', action='store_true')
    args.add_argument('-stop', help='Stop the server', action='store_true')
    args.add_argument('-path', help='Insert server exe path', required=True)
```

Right now on the `-stop` command I would like the required server to stop the thread execution but I'm not sure how i could accomplish this.

Comment: Please explain why it's a problem for your running application to tell the thread(s) to stop (by calling their `stop()` method).

Comment: i need to call that method from the outside through a command line argument as this application will be used technically by another application

Comment: If the application started the threads, then they "belong" to it, and only it can call their `stop()` methods. Seems to me like you need some way to communicate the desire that this needs to happen to it—which means some kind of interprocess communication will be required.

Comment: So i guess my only choises are: Listeners, sockets or making the application in an rpc which listens for commands (this way i could give it commands to stop threads belonging to it)

Comment: I think using one of those would be how it would need to be done. Even something simple like having the application poll the file system for the existence of special files, would work.